# Install joomla with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, joomla

I was trying to install joomla with MSSQL in my local windows system with the help of .

http://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_sqlserver

But,In my joomla installation ,There is no option for selecting MSSQL database ,How can i select MSSQL ,and install jooma?
I have experienced only in MYSQL

[image]

I have no experience in MSSQL .

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_sqlserver

Comment: @Stony That i have already read

Comment: Check if you have pdo's mssql driver enabled (I'm assuming joomla uses pdo).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the Joomla documentation in http://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_sqlserver

STEP 1

- Download and install Microsoft [drive] for PHP for SQL Server http://bit.ly/1uibvCi
- Download SQLSRV20.EXE to a temporary directory
- Run SQLSRV20.EXE
- When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory
- After extracting the files, read the Installation section of the SQLSRV20_Readme.htm file for next steps

STEP 2 
- install "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client" http://bit.ly/1uHaiCO

STEP 3 
- update your php.ini file add these lines :

extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll 
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll

Comment: I don't have time to install stuff; But since this is the official Joomla documentation, they should know how their product must work?

Comment: The link you are provided is already mentioned in my question

Comment: Here is a tutorial from the beginning:

STEP 1 - Download and install Microsoft [drive] for PHP for SQL Server
http://bit.ly/1uibvCi
- Download SQLSRV20.EXE to a temporary directory
- Run SQLSRV20.EXE
- When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory
- After extracting the files, read the Installation section of the SQLSRV20_Readme.htm file for next steps

STEP 2 - install "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client"
http://bit.ly/1uHaiCO

STEP 3 - update your php.ini file
add these lines :
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll